# variable/parameter is not defiened

Tags: javascript, constructor

```js
function user(name1, age, country) {
  this.name1 = name1;
  this.age = age;
  this.country = country;
}
user.prototype.yourName = function() {
  console.log(`Your Name Is ${name1}`);
}
user.prototype.yourAge = function() {
  console.log(`Your Age Is ${age} & Your Age In Days Is ${age*365}`);
}
user.prototype.yourCountry = function() {
  console.log(`Your Country Is ${country}`);
}
let firstUser = new user('Any Name', 'Any Age', 'Any Country');
firstUser.yourName(); //name1 Is Not Defined
firstUser.yourAge(); //age Is Not Defined
firstUser.yourCountry(); //country Is Not Defined
```

I don't know where is the problem!
it keeps saying name1 or age or country is not defined...

Comment: Use ``this.name1``, ``this.age``, ``this.country`` to print the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the this keyword before the variable to reference the instance variables of the object which is calling the method

```js
    function user(name1,age,country){
    this.name1=name1;
    this.age=age;
    this.country=country;
}
user.prototype.yourName=function(){
    console.log(`Your Name Is ${this.name1}`);
}
user.prototype.yourAge=function(){
    console.log(`Your Age Is ${this.age} & Your Age In Days Is ${this.age*365}`);
}
user.prototype.yourCountry=function(){
    console.log(`Your Country Is ${this.country}`);
}
let firstUser=new user('Any Name', 20 ,'Any Country');
firstUser.yourName();//name1 Is Not Defined
firstUser.yourAge();//age Is Not Defined
firstUser.yourCountry();//country Is Not Defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using prototype in Javascript

So prototype let you use the Object oriented syntax in vanila javascript where you can Inherit the property and method of a constructor.

So In your case

```
function user(name1,age,country){
    this.name1=name1;
    this.age=age;
    this.country=country;
}
```

Here in `user` method you defined your `constructor()` so you need to access the value in the method `user.prototype.yourName` method. Therefore you need to inherit the property of constructor using `this` because `user.prototype.yourName` will have it's own scope.

```
user.prototype.yourName=function(){
    console.log(`Your Name Is ${this.name1}`);
}
user.prototype.yourAge=function(){
    console.log(`Your Age Is ${this.age} & Your Age In Days Is ${this.age*365}`);
}
user.prototype.yourCountry=function(){
    console.log(`Your Country Is ${this.country}`);
}
```